# React JS. Рендер компонента при обновлении данных на сервере

Tags: reactjs

Пишу notify систему для пользователей. В целом все готово, но не могу понять как правильно сделать так, чтобы реакт отрисовал информацию при изменении данных на сервере. Т.е. обычно я с фронта обращаюсь к серверу и мог бы повесить deps на useEffect на какое-нибудь событие, но возможно есть лучше решение? Т.е. ситуация на сервере отработал скрипт, обновил данные в БД, -> react выдай оповещение. Возможно вопрос примитивен, не судите строго, новичек.

Comment: Вам нужны [сокеты](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks)

Comment: О, спасибо. Вроде в моем случае не супер сложно даже)